# How to allow multiple parameters to be passed into define_singleton_method

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, block

I want to create a class that can add methods dynamically and allow multiple parameters.

For example:

```
r = Robot.new
r.learn_maneuvering('turn') { |degree| puts "turning #{degree} degrees" }
r.turn 50 # => turning 50 degrees
r.turn 50, 60 # => turning 50 degrees # => turning 60 degrees
```

My first attempt was this:

```
def learn_maneuvering(name, &block)
    define_singleton_method(name, &block) 
end
```

However, it only accounts for one parameter..

I then started with:

```
def learn_maneuvering(name, &block)
    define_singleton_method(name) do |*args|
        # to do
    end
end
```

I believe this will loop until all arguments are used right? Anywho, I am not sure how to pass these arguments to the given block.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're close:

```
def learn_maneuvering(name, &block)
  define_singleton_method(name) do |*args|
    args.each do |arg|
      block.call(arg)
    end
  end
end

r = Robot.new
r.learn_maneuvering('turn') { |degree| puts "turning #{degree} degrees" }

r.turn 50, 60
```

prints:

> turning 50 degrees
>   turning 60 degrees

But is this really what you want? It seems like just doing

```
r.turn 50
r.turn 60
```

makes more sense to me.

Comment: Cool! Yes that is what I wanted thank you very much! How would I look this up on the Ruby 1.9.3 API to see what methods block has and what parameters the methods have? I know the website, but I mean do I just look for the keyword block?

Comment: A block is just a [Proc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Proc.html) with certain special treatments. Also, `block` is not a keyword, you could have just as easily done `&fooblock`.